# Is this a Callery Pear tree?

Tags: identification, trees, invasive

I just bought a house, in Ohio.  One of the trees in the backyard has many white flowers, which smell of...prosciutto?!?  Haha.  It's kinda cool, actually - but I think it might be a Callery Pear, and I'm not too keen on harboring an invasive species.  Is there anything else it could be?  If so, how would I distinguish them?  Pictures:

[image: Flowers]

[image: Full tree]

Comment: Does it have thorny protrusions on the branches?

Comment: @user1469762 Like, sharp?  Not as far as I've been able to find.  Closest I see is stubby branch nubs.

Comment: yes, very sharp. Sharp enough to pierce your skin. https://www.invasive.org/browse/detail.cfm?imgnum=5369496

Comment: @user1469762 Hmm.  Upon further research, I probably have a Bradford Pear, then - a particular cultivar of Callery Pear, lacking thorns.  It still cross-pollinates with other callery pears, though, and is still considered invasive.  Thanks